# Query to get data between months of a financial year

Tags: sql-server

I have to show the reports for expense in a financial year for all the months individually.
Currently I am getting the data for a particular month for all the expense names with the SUM(Amount), but I want to get the data for each months:-

For Example:

```
Name    |    Amount    |     Month

Tea     |    3600      |      Apr
Tea     |    8500      |      May
Tea     |    3600      |      June
Tea     |    300       |      July
Tea     |    360       |      Aug
Tea     |    600       |      Sep
Tea     |    870       |      Oct
```

Please help with the query how to get the data.
Thanks

Comment: Can you paste table structure?

Comment: Can u provide table schemas? Also as per your example it seems for each month only 1 type of expense is done (i.e. in apr only tea, may only sugar like wise), please confirm on this. If that is a case i believe Name is irrevelant for your query (i.e. field to come only select but no influence in record selection). So you can remove that field in above example to focus on real problem.

Comment: Yes Nitin, you are right, I will be passing the NameID from my code to get the data for all the months for that particular 'Name'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Amount) AS Amount, DATENAME(month, DateColumn) AS Month
FROM Table
GROUP BY Name, DATENAME(month, DateColumn)
```

Comment: Hey Lorentz, I tried this solution but it is giving the error:
"Column 'dateColumn' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." Also I will passing the NameID to get the data for that particular expense name for all the months.

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @FinYearStart DATETIME

DECLARE @FinYearEnd DATETIME

SET @FinYearStart = DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0, DATEADD( mm, -(((12 + DATEPART(m, getDate())) - 4)%12), getDate() ) - datePart(d,DATEADD( mm, -(((12 + DATEPART(m, getDate())) - 4)%12),getDate() ))+1 ) )

SET @FinYearEnd = DATEADD(SS,-1,DATEADD(mm,12,@FinYearStart))

SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS Amount, 

DATENAME(month, DATECOLUMN) AS Month,

DATEPART(month, DATECOLUMN) AS Month1

FROM TABLENAME where DATECOLUMN between @FinYearStart

AND @FinYearEnd GROUP BY 

DATENAME(month, DATECOLUMN),DATEPART(month, DATECOLUMN)

order by Month1
```

Comment: Have you seen the previous answer? While your code might work, don't you think this is overly complex?

Comment: Maybe it would be good if the Answerer explained what his code did.